# Cake Plenitude shape

Tags: cake, chocolate, mold

This image represent the Cake Plenitude by Pierre Herme. It is composed of chocolate pound cake, caramel sauce, chocolat au sel.
My main question is how to get this form of the cake. I make it with a normal cake mold,  but how to do it like this.

[image]

Comment: Maybe he use a custom cake form ? anyway, what's in the top part of the cake, just cake  ?

Comment: I think it's a huge piping of caramel ganache before enrobing with chocolat

Comment: at first I thought it was a cake with a croissant on top

Comment: @Dorothy sounds right to me. Doesn't look like a special cake pan at all, just a standard loaf pan.

Comment: Based on the ingredients list [here](http://www.pierreherme.com/products/pound-cakes1/cake-plenitude.html), you're missing the chocolate/caramel ganache from your description. "*Chocolate pound cake, dark chocolate chips with fleur de sel, smooth caramel, chocolate and caramel ganache.*"

Comment: I wonder if the piping on top is done separately, then just attached to the top of the loaf with liquid chocolate - the chocolate looks a bit thicker in the shadow of the piping.  That's how I thought it was done, essentially putting a filled chocolate on top of the loaf, and dipping the whole in chocolate - it would probably be easier to make a caramel-sauce filled mold than piping on a caramel sauce and dipping the whole loaf at once..

Comment: Yeah I think it's chocolate ganache on top. Worth to try.